# Compare historical rows (LAG rows) and combine changed values to single column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Compare historical rows (LAG rows based on ResultChngDt) and combine changed column values to single column. Looking for help in writing elegant/efficient SQL Server 2016 TSQL Code(without cursors).

I have a table with the structure and data like this:

```
+----+-------+--------------+---------------+--------+--------+--------------+
| ID | RepID | CollctedDate | CompletedDate | Result | Tcode  | ResultChngDt |
+----+-------+--------------+---------------+--------+--------+--------------+
| 1  | 101   | 11/20/2017   | 12/13/2017    |        | L-2190 | 12/13/2017   |
| 1  | 101   | 11/22/2017   | 12/15/2017    | POS    | L-Afb  | 1/5/2018     |
| 1  | 102   | 11/22/2017   | 12/15/2017    |        | L-2191 | 12/15/2017   |
| 1  | 102   | 11/22/2017   | 12/15/2017    | POS    | L-2192 | 12/31/2017   |
+----+-------+--------------+---------------+--------+--------+--------------+
```

I need to generate a report/result as follows:

```
+----+-------+---------------------------+--------------------------+--+
| ID | RepID | Previous                  | Current                  |  |
+----+-------+---------------------------+--------------------------+--+
| 1  | 101   | CollctedDate:11/20/2017   | CollctedDate:11/22/2017  |  |
|    |       | CompletedDate:12/13/2017  | CompletedDate:12/15/2017 |  |
|    |       | Result:                   | Result:POS               |  |
|    |       | Tcode:L-2190              | Tcode:L-Afb              |  |
| 1  | 102   | CollctedDate:11/22/2017   | CollctedDate:11/22/2017  |  |
|    |       | CompletedDate:12/15/2017  | CompletedDate:12/15/2017 |  |
|    |       | Result:                   | Result:POS               |  |
|    |       | Tcode:L-2191              | Tcode:L-2192             |  |
+----+-------+---------------------------+--------------------------+--+

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
    (
        [ID]            INT         NULL,
        [RepID]         INT         NULL,
        [CollctedDate]  DATETIME    NULL,
        [CompletedDate] DATETIME    NULL,
        [Result]        VARCHAR(3)  NULL,
        [Tcode]         VARCHAR(10) NULL,
        [ResultChngDt]  DATETIME    NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY];
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1] ([ID], [RepID], [CollctedDate], [CompletedDate], [Result], [Tcode], [ResultChngDt])
 VALUES (1, 101, N'11/20/2017', N'12/13/2017', N'', N'L-2190', N'12/13/2017') 
, (1, 101, N'11/22/2017', N'12/15/2017', N'POS', N'L-Afb', N'1/5/2018') 
, (1, 102, N'11/22/2017', N'12/15/2017', N'', N'L-2191', N'12/15/2017') 
, (1, 102, N'11/22/2017', N'12/15/2017', N'POS', N'L-2192', N'12/31/2017')
```

Comment: Please post your data as consumable SQL (CREATE TABLE followed by INSERT INTO) and the query you have so far

Comment: Please provide queries to create the table and to insert sample data. In addition please provide the requested result according to the sample data

Comment: Also you say generate a "report". In what? SSRS? PowerBI? Something else? What have you tried so far?

Comment: though I have posted questions in SO, I am new with posting table structure and code in here. Sorry for the jumbled table. I am providing the Table scripts with insert statement .

Comment: @Larnu, If it looks like a homework assignment for you, I believe you have a better solution and please provide an idea on how I could resolve this. "Report" could be SSRS/PowerBI hooking to Table 2 provided in my question.

Comment: So far, I tried creating single row with LAG() on all columns(EX:- LAG([CollctedDate],1,-1) OVER (Order by [ResultChngDt]) as [preCollctedDate], LAG([CompletedDate],1,-1) OVER (Order by [ResultChngDt]) as [preCompletedDate]  and so on...). The idea was to iterate through rows with cursor and the compare and update the current and change column in Table 2 if there is a difference in value of [CollctedDate] and [preCollctedDate], [CompletedDate] and [preCompletedDate].... (all columns that needs to be compared)

Comment: If you want something to look like your scond table, then you're proabably going to need a reporting tool, SQL Server doesn't do "multiline rows" like that. Though, I suppose, you could have a delimited list of data (with the delimiter being a carriage return and line break). Posting your `CREATE` and `INSERT` scripts is great step. Have you tried anything though? Can you post that, and explain the difficulties you had please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my query for your question:

```
    WITH cte_LEADLAG AS(
    SELECT ID,
           RepID,
           CollctedDate,
           CompletedDate,
           Result,
           Tcode,
           ResultChngDt,
           CONCAT('CollectedDate:',CAST(CollctedDate AS DATETIME2), ' CompletedDate:', CAST(CompletedDate AS DATETIME2), ' Result:', Result, ' Tcode', Tcode) AS dates,
           LAG(CollctedDate) OVER(PARTITION BY RepID ORDER BY CollctedDate) AS 'LAGCollectedDate'  ,
           lead(CollctedDate) OVER(PARTITION BY RepID ORDER BY CollctedDate) AS 'LEADCollectedDate',
           LAG(CompletedDate) OVER(PARTITION BY RepID ORDER BY CompletedDate) AS 'LAGCompDate'  ,
           lead(CompletedDate) OVER(PARTITION BY RepID ORDER BY CompletedDate) AS 'LEADcompDate' ,
           LEAD(Result) OVER(PARTITION BY RepID ORDER BY CompletedDate) AS 'LEADResult' ,
           LEAD(Tcode) OVER(PARTITION BY RepID ORDER BY CompletedDate) AS 'LEADTcode'    
    FROM #temp
    ),
     cte_FINAL AS(
    SELECT distinct ID,
                    RepID,
                    CASE WHEN cte.LAGCollectedDate IS NULL THEN CONCAT('CollectedDate:',CAST(CollctedDate AS DATETIME2), ' CompletedDate:', CAST(CompletedDate AS DATETIME2), ' Result:', Result, ' Tcode', Tcode) end AS 'Previous',
                    CASE WHEN cte.LEADCollectedDate IS not NULL THEN  CONCAT('CollectedDate:',CAST(cte.LEADCollectedDate AS DATETIME2), ' CompletedDate:', CAST(LEADcompDate AS DATETIME2), ' Result:', cte.LEADResult, ' Tcode', cte.LEADTcode) end AS 'Current'
    FROM cte_LEADLAG AS cte
    WHERE cte.LEADCollectedDate IN (SELECT MAX(LEADCollectedDate) FROM cte_LEADLAG WHERE cte_LEADLAG.RepID = cte.RepID))
)
    SELECT *
    FROM cte_FINAL;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank You Samita for the answer and the logic. That worked and sorry that SO is not allowing me to mark my vote for your answer!

Comment: When I vote, it gives the message that votes casts by those with less than 15 reputations are recorded, but do not change it publicly. There are some other Gold category volunteers here who claim to be "know all" are down-voting on questions, one loose the reputation here! Thanks again and I claim you as "Gold" category volunteer of SO.

Comment: Well, in time you will get 15 points and with that the permission to vote, and in the meantime you did the best action in my opinion which is saying thanks... A thanks is equal to 1000 points `:-)`  by the way, I sry I did not came back sooner after you added the queries to create the table and to insert sample data (I am not coming here a lot), and I am glad to see that you got an answer that fit you

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by RepID order by ResultChgDt desc) as rn
    from dbo.Table1
)
select
from data as d1 left outer join data as d2 on d2.rn = d1.rn + 1
where d1.rn = 1 -- I suppose you only want the two most recent??
```

This gives you all the data you need in a single row. You can handle report formatting to suit whatever requirements you have in whatever tool you're using for that.